# Login Server Side Logic

Tags: mysql, database, logic

This question has more to do with how I am setting up my server side code for a simple login script. I'm interested in the best way to achieve my goal, which is of course to verify a users username and password against a database and present them with either a successful login, a registration page, or a username or password found, but the alternative is wrong.

Right now, I have it set up where my sql query scans the database for both the user and pass:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE userName='" + userName + "' AND pass='" + password + "'"
```

Problem with this approach is it either returns a true or false...I cannot tell if one of the inputs was correct and the other wasn't. It either finds the record, or it doesn't.

So I could query based on the username alone, and if found check the record for the correct password before passing the user onto a successful login. That way I know if the password is wrong, but I have no idea if the password is right and the user simply types the wrong username.

Alternatively, I could extend on that, and if the user isn't found, requery the database based on the password and determine if I can find a record but the username doesn't match. It seems like a lot of back and forth with the database, which is fine. But i'd like to hear from some experts on whether or not this is a proper approach.

Comment: I don't see the point of querying on password alone. There should be nothing preventing multiple users from choosing the same password. From a security standpoint, you'd never want to give a user feedback that says "That password is already in use."

Comment: It's generally considered bad practice to provide too much information when handling unsuccessful logins - it provides hackers with information they can use to penetrate your system.
Check out the user flow on hotmail or google mail for what's currently the accepted way of doing this. Telling a hacker they got the right username but the wrong password tells them to keep trying different passwords; telling them they've got a valid password but not the right username allows them to test for the presence of common passwords (god, sex and password, according to folklore..)

Comment: Makes sense. This is the feedback i'm looking for. Thank you. Based on your feedback, is the way I am doing this currently, the proper method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to disclose too many information to people with bad intents trying to probe your system for available usernames (or even – god forbid – passwords that are in use).

When a login attempt failed, simply display a message stating:

> Username and/or password mismatch.

As an aside, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/PDO.prepare), rather than string concatenation when working with your database; it protects you from SQL injection attacks.
Plus – although it's not entirely clear from your code snippet – don't store plain passwords or plain password hashes. Rely on one of the many available and well tested encryption/hashing libraries e.g.  [PHP's crypt function](http://php.net/crypt) (make sure you select a proper hashing function such as SHA512).

Your code in the most simplest form would then look like this:

```
// coming from your login page
$dbh = new PDO(…);
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT `digest` FROM `users` WHERE `name` = :name LIMIT 1');
$sth->prepare(array( ':name' => $_POST['username'] ));
$result = $sth->fetch();

if($result !== FALSE && crypt($_POST['password'], $result['digest']) === $result['digest']) {
  printf('You logged in successfully as %s', htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']));
} else {
  echo 'Sorry, username and/or password did not match! Please try again.';
  sleep(1);
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not much idea wether stored procedure is supported in my sql or not. If it is supported then you can make SP like this way to check all cases. Below is code for MSSQL, you can check it with my sql :

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT [id] FROM [dbo].[users] WHERE [user_name] = @user_name AND [password] = @password)
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 AS RETURNVAL  --Valid User         
END
ELSE IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT [id] FROM [dbo].[users] WHERE [user_name] = @user_name)
BEGIN
    SELECT 0 AS RETURNVAL  -- User doesn't exist
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    SELECT -1 AS RETURNVAL  -- Password Not Correct
END
```

Comment: I am using mysql and last I knew, stored procedures were not supported, but maybe that has changed. I'll have to look into it. EDIT: It looks like stored procedure is supported so i'll give your query a try.

Comment: What if 2 users have the same password? On the MySQL subject - stored procs, functions, views, triggers etc. are supported since a long time ago.

Comment: @N.B. : 2 user have same password, but not same user name. In my query I have checked username and password in first case.

Comment: @UpendraChaudhari - what if we have two users with the same username? There was no mention on the unique constraints in the system by the author. Personally, I find your solution great, but the OP didn't provide sufficient info about the design of the login system.

Comment: @N.B. : Normally, this should not be case where 2 user have same username. But if it is then also EXIST condition check if any one record for that username and password. OP doesn't specified that he need details of that user, he just want to know it is valid or not and it is done by return value 1.

Comment: Duplicate usernames will not be allowed from the registration point, so that would not be an issue.